# Sed. Change the characters in a string that satisfying a pattern

Tags: linux, sed

I have a file with these lines:

```
abcd hfd ktr
hfk itor fld
fjkdf name fkld
ew wew name
```

It is necessary to change the characters in the lines that satisfy the pattern (contain the word 'name') as follows: a-> b, b-> c, c-> d ... z-> a, and apply these changes to the file. resulting in:

```
abcd hfd ktr
hfk itor fld
gkleg obnf glmf
fx xfx obnf
```

Comment: Can you give an example of input and output. As I can not workout what you are trying to do from the description.

Comment: Before:
abcd hfd ktr

hfk itor fld

fjkdf name fkld

ew wew name

After:

abcd hfd ktr
hfk itor fld

gkleg obnf glmf

fx xfx obnf

Comment: do you want to use/code  of any char to char+n value ?? if so sed will be harder to use than awk or bash :)

Comment: @bvl, update your question

Comment: I do it with tr, but i need to do it with sed. Now I can not change symbols using sed:(.

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
sed '/name/y/abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz/bcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyza/' infile
```